What is an upper bound on $\frac{\|S\|}{S^T \cdot 1_{n\times 1}}$ for $S \in \mathbb{N}^n$?
Let $S \in \mathbb{N}^n$. I want to upper bound
$$
q = \frac{\|S\|}{S^T\cdot 1_{n\times 1}}
$$
What I did so far, is see that $q < 1$ since
$$
q^2 = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n s_k^2}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n s_k \right)^2} < 1
$$

When $n>1$, it is easy to see that $1$ is an unattainable supremum of $q$: fix any $s_2,s_3,\ldots,s_n$. Then $q\to1$ when $s_1\to\infty$.

Even more, I somehow think that $\frac{1}{n}$ is more like a fitting upper bound, but I cannot properly express this intuition

$\frac1n$ is a lower bound of $q^2$, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

@user1551 I think your example just shows that in general, one cannot expect a better upper bound than $1$

@user1551 I guess that this is settled then: $\frac{1}{n} \leq q^2 \leq 1$.

You can get somewhere with the inverse Cauchy inequality. If $M = \max_k \{s_k \}$, then it states
$$
C  \left(\sum_{k=1}^n s_k \cdot 1 \right)^2 \ge \sum_{k=1}^n s_k^2 \sum_{k=1}^n 1^2 
$$
with $C = \frac14 \frac{(1+M)^2}{M}$, whis is
$$
 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n s_k \right)^2   \ge \sum_{k=1}^n s_k^2 \frac{4 M n }{(1+M)^2}
$$
Hence
$$
 q^2 \le \frac{(1+M)^2}{4 M n}
$$
